# select cell in range inputs value into cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below that i got working, when i select a cell in a range, an input box pops up and my input is sent to the same cell i clicked but in sheet 2. I want to take this one step further. i want to bypass the input box completely and just send the value F, and i only want to do this after i click cell b2. so cell b2 would have to work as some kind of toggle (maybe put an invisible shape over it to act as a button?)

Example 1: sheet 1, select cell B2 turns on macro, select cell in range example: D10 inputs the letter F into cell D10 on sheet 2, select cell B2 turns off macro so if i select cell D10 or any cell in that range nothing will happen anymore. it would also need to remove the value F from D10 if the cell is clicked again while the macro is on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim xRtn As Variant
     If Selection.Count = 1 Then
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9:AS20")) Is Nothing Then
             xRtn = Application.InputBox("Insert your value please")
             Sheets("2020").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRtn

         End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested. I'm not sure if I understood all of your objectives.

I think if you add a checkbox to your worksheet (resize and store it wherever you want; maybe in cell `B2`) called "Check Box 1" then the below code should work.

One way of adding a check box might be: `Excel > Developer > Insert > Check Box (Form Control)` (depending on your Excel version). If the `Developer` tab is not visible, you may need to [get it to show](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45) first.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetCheckBox() As Shape
    Set GetCheckBox = Me.Shapes("Check Box 1")
End Function

Private Function IsCheckBoxTicked() As Boolean
    IsCheckBoxTicked = (GetCheckBox.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1)
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D9:AS20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If IsCheckBoxTicked() Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2020").Range(Target.Address)
            .Value = IIf(.Value = "F", Empty, "F")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that is working almost perfectly!! when i select b2 then select a cell in my range it send F exactly like i wanted, pressing b2 again turns it off just like i wanted. the clear contents isnt working as intended though.
<br/>
Example: i click b2, then E9, E10 and E11, those 3 cells now have the value F in sheet 2, perfect, what i want is when i click E9, E10 and E11 again for the cell value to clear, this doesnt happen, I have to first click b2 again then click those cells to clear contents

Comment: Conclusion:it needs to be b2 toggle on, then when i click a cell in my range, if it has no value give it a value of F, if has a value, clear its value, b2 or clicking anywhere outside of range toggle off

Comment: correction, once active press b2 again doesnt turn off the macro, it make clicks clear contents, so no matter what a click is either sends F or clears contents, this is not what i intended, i want b2=turn macro on/off

Comment: @ChrisR, have re-written this if you want to have another go. I've switched to a check box since `Worksheet_SelectionChange` requires the selection to change. If you keeping clicking an already selected cell, the selection technically isn't changing -- which means clicking `B2` consecutively won't turn things on/off. A check box should be okay.

Comment: works perfectly, now i need a way to hide the checkbox, i have positioned it over cell b2 like you said it would be perfect if there was some way to make it invisible, or maybe i can move the checkbox somewhere hidden and there is a way the cell b2 toggles wether the checkbox is ticked not ticked?

Comment: Solved it, i made a rectangle and made a macro that toggled my checkbox on and off, then i made the rectangle invisible on cell b2. Thank you so much chillin